# TLS fatal alert code 48 on Azure web role

Tags: azure, ssl, https, azure-web-roles

We're experiencing random timeouts on our azure web role and I'm trying to rule out if this alert code is the cause. When I RDP into the role and check the Event Viewer, I'm seeing hundreds of these errors in the event log:

> A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol
>   defined fatal alert code is 48.

[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/10/06/ssl-tls-alert-protocol-amp-the-alert-codes.aspx) gives more info for alert code 48:

> Received a valid certificate chain or partial chain, but the
>   certificate was not accepted because the CA certificate could not be
>   located or could not be matched with a known, trusted CA. This message
>   is always fatal.

We do have an SSL certificate on the server, have setup the azure configuration to use it, and are able to browse the site under https.

What does this error and description mean and how do I go about fixing it? I'm not really sure how to move forward with this info, as it's the first time I've setup a site with SSL.